# Jest exits before tests are finished running

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm trying to create Jest unit tests for async functions. The docs (https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous) are quite straightforward and have been used to write the following function and unit test:

```
// Code
async function fetchData() {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    return 1
}
// Test
test('test should fail', async function() {
    const data = await fetchData()
    expect(data).toBe('abc')
});
```

It seems like Jest exits before the async function gets a chance to finish as you can see from the result below.

```
$ npm test

> test
> jest


 RUNS  ...mymodule/__tests__/mymodule.test.js
```

As many have suggested in other posts, I've tried to set a timeout value - both globally and locally to the test. But this hasn't helped. Maybe this has something to do with my environment, but I haven't found what could be the cause. Any suggestions?

- jest v27.5.1
- jest-dev-server v6.0.3 ( - have tried to remove this just in case, but did not help.)
- node v17.6.0
- npm v8.5.1

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "node",
  globalSetup: "./jest-setup",  // tested with and without
  globalTeardown: "./jest-teardown", // tested with and without
  testTimeout: 30000, // tested with and without
}
```

Comment: code looks legit to me. How jest does behave? "Test passed"? How about adding `expect(1).toBe(2)` after `await`? Would it make test fail?

Comment: No, it won't fail with ```expect(1).toBe(2)``` even. As long as I have an await, Jest's behaviour is that it quits before the test has a chance to complete. So the output never states FAIL or PASS, only RUNS.

Comment: If I were to remove the ```await``` keyword when calling the function, then JEST would FAIL with both ```expect(1).toBe(2)``` and ```expect(data).toBe(2)```.

Comment: how about using `.then()` instead of `await`? `return fetchData().then(data => { expect(data).toBe('abc); return data;})`? does it work fine?

Comment: No, the same happens with ```.then()```.

Comment: I just moved the test to a brand new node project, and it works just fine there. I have the same versions of jest and jest-dev-server and using the exact same Jest configurations as in my original project.

Comment: Another interesting piece of info: When I debug and set a breakpoint at ```expect(...)``` and wait a bit before continuing the program, the test fails as expected.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I try to run a single file with jest. The command terminates before executing the tests. Then I try with the `--watch` argument to enable watch mode which solved my issue to run all the tests and print result.

Answer (score 0):

I removed globalSetup from the config, and that fixed the issue. I thought I'd tried that before, but apparently not.

The cause was a command within the initialisation of jest-dev-server in globalSetup that failed. Because of that, Jest quit without letting me know that it had failed. Example is shown below:

```
const { setup } = require("jest-dev-server")
module.exports = async () => {
    await setup({ command: "theFailing cmd" })
}
```